# How Do I Properly Deploy With An Integration Test Project?

Tags: maven, deployment

My projects are structured as:

```
root
  common
  client
  server
  test
```

server and client depend on common. test is a project that contains integration tests and these tests depend on client common and server.

If I add all of these as modules to root, then when I execute mvn deploy on root it will deploy the jars, and then run the integration tests. I only want to hit the deploy phase if my integration tests run successfully.

Is this possible with Maven?

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't run mvn deploy directly but use the [release plugin](https://maven.apache.org/maven-release/maven-release-plugin/) instead. You have to run

`mvn release:prepare release:perform`

for doing and deplying a relase. See also [this blog post](http://developer-blog.cloudbees.com/2012/12/should-you-deploy-snapshots.html) about deploying snapshots.